# Resume multipart upload with TransferUtility amazon-s3

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there anyway to do a multipart upload using the AmazonS3 TransferUtility class and also be able to resume if the the upload fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't seem to be possible using this class.

You have to do it manually using lower-level classes and handle yourself part numbers and ETags in a (persistant) data structure.